# Git command line - know if in submodule?

Tags: git, bash, command-prompt, git-submodules

Is there any way in git to know if you're in a submodule? You can do thinks like `git submodule foreach` in the parent directory but I can't seem to come up with a generic way to show that you're in a submodule if you're in one, or in any of the child directories inside the submodule.

I guess you could find the repo root with `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, and then cd-ing up a level, and finding the root of that repo again and then comparing the list of submodules to the current directory, but that seems so sticky...

Comment: for anyone who finds this, here's the project i used this in http://andrewray.me/bash-prompt-builder/index.html

Comment: What about `git rev-parse --git-dir | grep '\.git/modules'`? Or simply `git rev-parse --git-dir` if you just need the git directory.

Comment: Note: with Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), the actual command to use would be `git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree`. See my [edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7359782/6309).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a shell function that you can use to detect this:

```
function is_submodule() 
{       
     (cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.." && 
      git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree) | grep -q true
}
```

**Edit** In response to your proposed script:

Looking good.

- <strike>There is a bug in</strike>

  ```
  for line in $submodules; do cd "$parent_git/$line"; \
      if [[ `pwd` = $_git_dir ]]; then return 0; fi; \
  done
  ```

*because it won't cd back (so it would only work if the first submodule
is a match). My version checks without changing directories; That could be done done by `cd`-ing in a subshell, but returning the exitcode is getting complicated that way*

- I don't know where you get `$_git_dir` from - I used `basename`(1) to get that
  information (see below).
- There was also a problem with submodules containing a space in the name. *In my version, there is still a problem with newlines in submodule names left, but I don't care enough to fix that. (Note the 'idiomatic' way to avoid having the `while read` in a subshell without needing new bash-isms like `readarray`)*
- finally declaring all the vars local fixes potential problems when using this
  inside other scripts (e.g. when the outer script uses the `$path` variable...)
- I renamed `_git_dir` to `top_level` (which is less confusing, because GIT_DIR means something else)

#### Remaining issues:

- I don't know whether git supports it (*I don't think so*) but this script could fail if the submodule directory is a symlink (because "$top_level/.." might resolve outside the containing repository)
- submodule names with newlines will not be recognized properly
- I also suggest you trap errors (either with 'set -e', 'trap "return 1"
  ERR' or similar) -- *not in my script/exercise for reader*

```
#!/bin/bash

function is_submodule() {
    local top_level parent_git module_name path
    # Find the root of this git repo, then check if its parent dir is also a repo
    top_level="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
    module_name="$(basename "$top_level")"
    parent_git="$(cd "$top_level/.." && git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null)"
    if [[ -n $parent_git ]]; then
        # List all the submodule paths for the parent repo
        while read path
        do
            if [[ "$path" != "$module_name" ]]; then continue; fi
            if [[ -d "$top_level/../$path" ]];    then return 0; fi
        done < <(cd $parent_git && git submodule --quiet foreach 'echo $path' 2> /dev/null)
        #return 1
    fi
    return 1
}
```

#### Usage

```
if is_submodule; then
    echo "In a submodule!"
else
    echo "Not in a submodule"
fi
```

Comment: Would this return a false positive if you simply have a repo checked out inside a repo?

Comment: @Andy: yes it would. So you may change the name to is_nested_worktree

Comment: I modified the function to eliminate false positives, do you have any suggestions? https://gist.github.com/1208078

Comment: @Andy: I have proposed an improved script based on yours (see also https://gist.github.com/1208393)

Comment: I think you're mistaken about the `cd` bug, `cd "$parent_git/$line"` will be a full path, not a relative one.

Comment: @Andy: aha. Indeed the manpage says so. I still think it is better to avoid unnecessary directory changing (again to avoid unexpected effects on calling scripts). What about `is_submodule || git reset --hard`: it could reset a random other submodule if the current working tree was not a submodule. Hope the rest of it helped.

Answer (score 43):

(Update April 2017 for Git 2.13, Q2 2017)

There is now an official command to determine if a repo is a submodule of a parent repo:

```
cd /path/to/potential/submodule/repo
git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree
```

See [commit bf0231c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf0231c66140be5194ac76a4a9f79e949c588293) (08 Mar 2017) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3edcc04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3edcc048621fee389be6991c90b6a7dd0386c57e), 17 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `rev-parse`: add `--show-superproject-working-tree`

> In some situations it is useful to know if the given repository
> is a submodule of another repository.
>
> Add the flag `--show-superproject-working-tree` to `git-rev-parse` to make it easy to find out if there is a superproject.
> When no superproject exists, the output will be empty.

[Jethro Yu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542730/jethro-yu) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359204/git-command-line-know-if-in-submodule/7359782?noredirect=1#comment92619285_7359782):

> get super project path regardless inside/outside of submodule:
>
> ```
> git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree --show-toplevel | head -1
> ```

---

(Update 2014) As noted by [Quentin Pradet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/481584/quentin-pradet), more recent Git submodule repos show a simple `.git` *file* instead of a `.git` folder.
That `.git` file reference the path of the actual submodule git repo, stored in the *parent* repo `.git/modules` subfolder.

[jeffrson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564226/jeffrson) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359204/git-command-line-know-if-in-submodule/7359782#comment134143027_7359782) (2023):

> Existing '`.git`' itself is not sufficient, because that's the same for worktrees.
> However, the file should contain the string "`modules`" or "`worktrees`", respectively, as part of the target.

---

(Original answer: Sept. 2011)

The very nature of a submodule is for the git repo acting as submodule has no idea it is used as a submodule by a parent repo.

One dirty trick would be to:

- change a file
- go back one level above the current repo
- try a "`git status --ignore-submodules=none`"
- restore the changed file.

If you see the file in the result of the `git status`, your repo should be a submodule.
If it is only a nested repo, the `git status` should ignore your nested repo entirely.

Comment: Is it still true? At least with git 2.1.2, submodules contain a simple ".git" file saying "gitdir: relative/path/to/parent/.git/modules/path/to/submodule/".

Comment: @QuentinPradet True. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. A `.git` *file* should means the repo is a submodule.

Comment: get super project path regardless inside/outside of submodule:
git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree --show-toplevel | head -1

Comment: @JethroYu Thank you. I have included your link in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thank you for pointing at '--show-superproject-working-tree'. BTW, existing '.git' itself is not sufficient, because that's the same for worktrees. However, the file should contain the string "modules" or "worktrees", respectively, as part of the target.

Comment: @JeffRSon Good point, thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 5):

try `git rev-parse --git-dir` which will return `".git"` if and only if called from the project root:

```
if `git rev-parse --git-dir` == ".git"
    // in root directory
else
    // in submodule directory
```

unless you set `$GIT_DIR` which will be the returned value in that case (see [rev-parse](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)):

> --git-dir
>
> Show $GIT_DIR if defined. Otherwise show the path to the .git directory. The path shown, when relative, is relative to the current working directory.
>
> If $GIT_DIR is not defined and the current directory is not detected to lie in a Git repository or work tree print a message to stderr and exit with nonzero status.

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't seem to work for nested submodules.

Comment: @KeithSmiley I think it works for nested submodules as well. At least in current last version 2.9.3. If you create a submodule via `git submodule add... `  rather than `git clone ...` in the submodule.

Comment: This one seems to be the most effective way; in essence all you need is `is_submodule() { ! [[ "$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)" =~ \.git$ ]]; }`

Comment: A little update: run the check from the toplevel dir:
`alias issub='( cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) && test $(git rev-parse --git-dir) != ".git"; )'`

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work in a worktree (which itself actually is a project root)

Answer (score 3):

I tried the script suggested above and it didn't work for me.  Of course, I may be the only person in the world who has a submodule that's not a direct child of the parent module.  The code above assumes that it is.

It would also be nice to then show the submodule path inside the parent - I plan to use this to show a bash shell prompt telling me if I'm in a submodule, and where.

Here's my update:

```
function is_submodule() {
    local git_dir parent_git module_name path strip
    # Find the root of this git repo, then check if its parent dir is also a repo
    git_dir="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
    parent_git="$(cd "$git_dir/.." && git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null)"

    if [[ -n $parent_git ]]; then
        strip=$((${#parent_git} + 1))
        module_name=${git_dir:$strip}
        # List all the submodule paths for the parent repo
        while read path
        do
            if [[ "$path" != "$module_name" ]]; then continue; fi
            if [[ -d "$parent_git/$path" ]]; then
                echo $module_name
                return 0;
            fi
        done < <(cd $parent_git && git submodule --quiet foreach 'echo $path' 2> /dev/null)
    fi
    return 1
}

# Usage
submodule=$(is_submodule)
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "In a submodule! $submodule"
else
    echo "Not in a submodule"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer doesn't work for submodules that aren't at the top level.  This does and is also simpler:

```bash
function is_git_submodule() {
    local module_name 

    module_path="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2> /dev/null)"

    # List all the submodule paths for the parent repo and look for our module's path
    (cd "${module_path}/.." && git submodule --quiet foreach 'echo $toplevel/$path' 2> /dev/null) | \
        grep --quiet --line-regexp --fixed-strings "$module_path"
}
```