# Git push doesnt upload folders inside main folder

Tags: git

I have the following projects in a folder structure.

- Homework

  - Ex1

    - main.cpp
    - class1.cpp
    - readme.txt
  - Ex2

    - main.cpp
    - class2.cpp
    - readme.txt
  - Ex3

    - main.cpp
    - class3.cpp
    - readme.txt
  - readme.txt

I want to submit this whole 'project' to a given repository(which I've already set up). So I first did cd to the Homework directory and did

```
$git init
```

Then I did

```
$git add --all
```

After that I commited by

```
$git commit -m "Adding all folders"
```

Then did the push as

```
$git push origin master
```

After this when I opened the repository URL on browser I see only the readme.txt in Homework directory. I don't see the Ex1,Ex2,Ex3 folders and their contents.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have a `.gitignore` file with the pattern `Ex*` in it?

Comment: @SaulloCastro No I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Ex1`, `Ex2` and `Ex3` have their own `.git` folder, there would be considered as nested Git repos, and would be ignored by a `git add`.

[If those `.git` are files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359782/6309), that would make them **[submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

Comment: Seems that will suffice my requirement. Does this mean I have to go to each Ex1 Ex2 folders and create a .git file?

Comment: @PasanW no, I was saying "if you see a `.git` folder/file in those `Exn` folders, that would explain why a `git add` wouldn't work". Do you see a `.git` folder or file in those `Exn` folders?

Comment: There IS a .git directory in these Exn folders. Shall I delete them?

Comment: @PasanW that would be one way indeed, but first, go in one of those `Exn` folder, and type "`git remote -v`", to see what their remote url is. If there is none, and you want only one bug repo, then yes, removing the `.git` folder would work (but would loose the individual history of those sub-repos)

Comment: Git remote -v inside an Exn folder gives::
origin ssh://git@ip/sandbox/pcccc.git (fetch)
origin ssh://git@ip/sandbox/pccc.git (push)

Answer (score 0):

Pushing Folder to repository.

Step 1)Make sure you have a repository or create new one to 
       which the folder will be pushed.

Step 2)Now in desktop go to that folder(which is to be 
       uploaded).

Step 3)Now in that folder ; right click "Git Bash here".

Step 4)Type command :

```
$ git init
$ git add.
$ git config --global user.name <github user_name>
$ git commit -m "first commit"
```

IV.1)Add remote repository URL(in github account>your 
    repository) to**

```
$ git remote add origin <paste the URL>
```

(URL looks 
     like:https://github.com//.git

```
$ git push origin master
```

Step 5)Confirm

Step 6)Uploading takes place.Now refresh your repository in 
github account.

Step 7)Folder is uploaded .